# How to correctly wrap Material UI v5 component to force the Grow component work properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm a React newbie, so I apologise in advance, if there are any stupid mistakes or inaccuracies.
I have a working code of my Blog page:

```
export default function Blog() {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [visiblePosts, setVisiblePosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogPhotos().then((result) => {
      setPhotos(result);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutIds = photos.map((_, index) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisiblePosts((prev) => [...prev, index]);
      }, index * 300)
    );

    return () => {
      timeoutIds.forEach((id) => clearTimeout(id));
    };
  }, [photos]);

  return (
    <Box sx={{ m: 3, pb: "10vh" }}>
      <Paper
        elevation={6}
        sx={{
          minHeight: "80vh",
          width: "100%",
          boxShadow: 5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
          backdropFilter: "blur(8px)",
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ p: 5 }}>
          <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center">
            {!photos ? (
              <Box
                display="flex"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                sx={{ color: "#FFF", height: "100%" }}
              >
                <CircularProgress
                  color="inherit"
                  sx={{ position: "absolute", top: "45%" }}
                />
              </Box>
            ) : (
              photos.map((photo, index) => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={index}>
                  <Grow
                    in={visiblePosts.includes(index)}
                    style={{ transformOrigin: "0 0 0" }}
                    timeout={500}
                  >
                    <Card
                      sx={{
                        minWidth: 175,
                        maxWidth: 600,
                        boxShadow: 5,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        m: 2,
                      }}
                    >
                      <CardActionArea>
                        <CardMedia
                          component="img"
                          height="140"
                          image={photo.urls.small}
                        />
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                            Lizard
                          </Typography>
                          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles,
                            with over 6,000 species, ranging across all
                            continents except Antarctica
                          </Typography>
                        </CardContent>
                      </CardActionArea>
                    </Card>
                  </Grow>
                </Grid>
              ))
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I wanted to wrap a part of code to a component like this:

```
const BlogPost = ({ photo }) => {
  return (
    <Card
      sx={{ minWidth: 175, maxWidth: 600, boxShadow: 5, borderRadius: 5, m: 2 }}
    >
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia component="img" height="140" image={photo.urls.small} />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default BlogPost;
```

But problem is that BlogPost component's code doesn't work with a Grow component. I've tried to use **forwardRef**, but nothing changed: BlogPost cards doesn't appear one by one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else still needs a fixed modification (silly, but working), here's the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { NavLink as Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";
import Grow from "@mui/material/Grow";
import { getBlogPhotos } from "../../services/PhotoService";
import BlogPostTitles from "../../services/DataService";
import BlogCard from "../BlogCard/BlogCard";
import { Paper } from "@mui/material";

function BlogList() {
  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [visiblePosts, setVisiblePosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogPhotos(6).then((result) => {
      setPhotos(result);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutIds = photos.map((_, index) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisiblePosts((prev) => [...prev, index]);
      }, index * 300)
    );

    return () => {
      timeoutIds.forEach((id) => clearTimeout(id));
    };
  }, [photos]);
  return (
    <Box sx={{ m: 3, pb: "10vh" }}>
      <Paper
        elevation={6}
        sx={{
          minHeight: "80vh",
          width: "100%",
          boxShadow: 5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
          backdropFilter: "blur(8px)",
        }}
      >
        <Box component="ul" sx={{ p: 5, listStyle: "none" }}>
          <Grid container spacing={2} justifyContent="center">
            {photos.length === 0 ? (
              <Box
                display="flex"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                sx={{ color: "#FFF", height: "100%" }}
              >
                <CircularProgress
                  color="inherit"
                  sx={{ position: "absolute", top: "45%" }}
                />
              </Box>
            ) : (
              Object.entries(BlogPostTitles).map(([slug, { title }], index) => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} key={index}>
                  <Grow
                    in={visiblePosts.includes(index)}
                    style={{ transformOrigin: "0 0 0" }}
                    timeout={500}
                  >
                    <Box component="li" key={slug}>
                      <Link
                        to={`/blog/${slug}`}
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
                      >
                        <BlogCard
                          img={photos[index].urls.small}
                          title={title}
                        />
                      </Link>
                    </Box>
                  </Grow>
                </Grid>
              ))
            )}
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default BlogList;
```

My BlogCard

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { deepOrange, yellow } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@mui/material/CardMedia";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: deepOrange,
    secondary: yellow,
  },
});

export default function BlogCard({ img, title }) {
  return (
    <Card
      sx={{
        minWidth: 175,
        maxWidth: 600,
        boxShadow: 5,
        borderRadius: 5,
        m: 2,
      }}
    >
      <CardMedia component="img" height="140" image={img} />
      <CardContent>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
          {title}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

My BlogPost

```
import React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import NotFoundPage from "../../pages/NotFoundPage";
import BlogPostTitles from "../../services/DataService";
import { deepOrange, yellow } from "@mui/material/colors";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: deepOrange,
    secondary: yellow,
  },
});

export default function BlogPost() {
  const { slug } = useParams();
  const post = BlogPostTitles[slug];
  if (!post) {
    return <NotFoundPage />;
  }
  const { title, description } = post;
  return (
    <Box sx={{ m: 3, pb: "10vh" }}>
      <Paper
        elevation={6}
        sx={{
          minHeight: "80vh",
          width: "100%",
          boxShadow: 5,
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)",
          backdropFilter: "blur(8px)",
        }}
      >
        <Box sx={{ p: 5 }}>
          <Typography variant="h1" color="primary" theme={theme}>
            {title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h3" color="secondary" theme={theme}>
            {description}
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Added React Router version 6.4.